# Why forEach method wont work in component returning function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components

Why on the lower example in createGrid i have to use array.map method when forEach is almost the same with

```
import React from 'react';
import Square from './Square.js'

const Board = ({squaresList}) => {
    const createGrid = squaresList.map((item, i) => { // squareList.forEach not working here - not returning <Square/> components.
        return(
            <Square key={i}id={item.id}/>
        )
    })
        return(
            <div className='game-board-container'>
                <div className='squares-container'>
                    {createGrid}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
}

export default Board;
```

Comment: See the linked duplicate and the notice the return value of `forEach` [is `undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` creates a new array whereas `forEach` just loops through the array. In this case, we want `createGrid` to be an array of `Square` components. If you use `forEach` then, `createGrid` will be undefined.

According to MDN

> The map() method creates a new array populated with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

whereas in forEach

> The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.

Answer (score 1):

Becuase `Array.prototype.map()` returns a new Array and `Array.prototype.forEach()` returns `undefined`.

The choice between `map()` and `forEach()` will depend on your use case. If you plan to change, alternate, or use the data, you should pick `map()`, because it returns a new array with the transformed data.

But, if you won't need the returned array, don't use `map()` - instead use `forEach()` or even a `for` loop.

Check out the article from [FreeCodeCamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/4-main-differences-between-foreach-and-map/). They wrote a nice article about the differences between these two methods.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach()` method doesn’t actually return anything (undefined). It simply calls a provided function on each element in your array. This callback is allowed to mutate the calling array.

`map()` method will also call a provided function on every element in the array. The difference is that `map()` utilizes return values and actually returns a new Array of the same size.